# Wordpress SQL query how to select posts that match regex for title but are not in a certain category

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I can get it working for `posts that match a title and are in a category`, however I cannot get  `posts that match a title and are NOT in a category`

```
select * 
from wp_posts 
join wp_term_relationships on (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
 where (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id NOT in (107))
 and (post_title REGEXP 'video|film' ) 
 and (post_type = 'post' OR post_type = 'xdays1')
 GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
```

It has the same amount of results as this, without any category code:

```
select * 
from wp_posts 
WHERE
(post_title REGEXP 'video|film' ) 
 and (post_type = 'post' OR post_type = 'xdays1')
 GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
```

I assume my syntax is wrong...

I have about 200 posts in category with id 107. So I want results to not include those.

help appreciated!

Comment: Sans proper aliases and sample data, not much can be said here.  It is certainly possible that the join would not reduce the size of the result set between the 2 queries.

Comment: how do I post sample data / results when its over wp 5000 posts? also logically: if the first statement wants results NOT in a category, and the second statement includes all results including that category, then I assume the first statement is not working to ignore a category?

Comment: maybe I should rephrase, for wp - what is the correct SQL to "list posts that match a certain title and do not exist in a certain category". I want to use only SQL (as its thousands of posts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use "join". Try the following code instead, see if you could get it to work.

```sql
SELECT wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE (wp_posts.post_title REGEXP 'video|film' )
AND ( wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (107) ) ) 
AND (wp_posts.post_type = 'post' OR wp_posts.post_type = 'xdays1') 
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Comment: brilliant, that works!! thanks a million @Ruvee

Comment: I didnt realise the checkmark existed. Done!! :)